# smarty foreach last not working correctly?

Tags: php, html, smarty

im having troubles with adding a class to the last option from foreach, its repeating it for some reason any ideas??

```
{if $subcategories} 
<div class="subcategories">
{if $subcategories|@count < 6}
    <ul>
{/if}
{foreach from=$splitted_subcategories item="ssubcateg"}
    {if $subcategories|count >= 6}
        <div class="subcategories">
            <ul>
    {/if}
        {foreach from=$ssubcateg item=category name="ssubcateg"}
        {if $category.category_id}<li{if $smarty.foreach.ssubcateg.last} class="last"{/if}><a href="{"categories.view?category_id=`$category.category_id`"|fn_url}" class="strong">{$category.category}</a></li>{/if}

    {/foreach}
    {if $subcategories|count >= 6}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
{if $subcategories|count < 6}
</ul>
{/if}
</div>
{/if}
```

output:
seems to be repeating? and if there are 6 results is adds one class="last" but the middle result as in 3rd result?

```
<ul> 
<li class="last"><a class="strong" href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a class="strong" href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a class="strong" href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a class="strong" href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't know why you decided to do what you just did.  If you posted a question and didn't get the response you were looking for, [deleting it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050215/smarty-foreach-last-not-working-correctly-where-have-i-gone-wrong) and reposting the exact same question is not the correct way to go about things here.  Please don't do that.

Comment: sorry, assumed it was older and went down in priority for people to see and was hoping for a response. wont do that again though.

Comment: I'm just curious, what syntax is this?

Comment: html and smarty (php templating language)

Comment: We have a bounty system to help bring attention to your questions.  See this section in the [faq#bounty] for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last item is repeating, because you're checking for »being last in the inner looop«. you're neglecting that the inner loop itself is looped. try:

```
{foreach from=$splitted_subcategories item="ssubcateg" name="outer"}
  {foreach from=$ssubcateg item=category name="ssubcateg"}
    {if $smarty.foreach.outer.last && $smarty.foreach.ssubcateg.last}
      …
```

Comment: there was a typo in "ssubcateg". try again